# WordPress linking to external script

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

Trying to add external javascript file (located in folder called js) to custom WP theme. The following technique inside functions.php does not produce any results besides: **FATAL ERROR:** Allowed memory size exhausted

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'site_resources');

function site_resources() {
  //stylesheet
  wp_enqueue_style("style",get_stylesheet_uri());

  //main script
  wp_enqueue_scripts(main_script, "js/main");
}
```

I have tried commenting out the actual enqueue script and adding a normal link to the file in the header.php. Again, no result, although this time it doesn't break.

The main.js file is composed of an alert.

Comment: is it very big js file?

Comment: @FastSnail `The main.js file is composed of an alert.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is the right syntax for the wp_enqueue_script:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'client-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/client.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.0', true );
```

Read the following post:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Answer (score 0):

```
function site_resources() {

  //stylesheet
  wp_deregister_style('style');
  wp_enqueue_style("style",get_stylesheet_uri());

  //main script
  wp_deregister_script('main_script');
  wp_enqueue_scripts(main_script, "js/main");

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'site_resources');
```

Maybe you should try this.